# Can someone please help me find examples of the following if they exist or not.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

I am looking to find examples of the following if they exist or not. A group with exactly 7 elements and a binary operation on a set $S$ with identity, such that not every element $a \in S$ has an inverse. Its a question that I am really stuck on.

Comment: Integers modulo $7$ and real numbers under multiplication.

Comment: Is multiplication on the integers a binary operation such that not every element in the integers has an inverse? Inverse of 1 is 1, inverse of -1 is -1, but the 2 does not have an inverse.

Comment: By definition of a group, every element has an inverse.

Comment: @user503154 I thought you asked for two different counter-examples. The first example I gave was for a group with 7 elements. Second example for a binary operation with an identity such that at least one eelment does not have an inverse. ($0$ doesn't have an inverse in my example).

Comment: This question is not clear. Also, try not to just post questions, as people won't know where to start to be able to help you (and you will get downvotes and close votes, as happened here). Try to explain what you have tried and where and why you got stuck/need help. It would also help if you said where you found this question (week X of course Y, where we covered topic Z).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $S=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and define multiplication $\odot$ by

$a\odot b := a\cdot b \text{ mod } 7$

Clearly $1$ is the identity with respect to that multiplication. But $0$ has no inverse.